# Have an error " error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, mysql, pip, installation, cl.exe

try install mysql-python

```
C:\Users\Одиночка>pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\2871~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-lyj5ba\\mysql-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\2871~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-y0f9do-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Maybe it's depending on some software you don't have installed. That looks like a Visual Studio component, so you may need to install that first. No compiler = Not going to happen.

Comment: System got this file on path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin""

Comment: Clearly it hasn't otherwise it would find `cl.exe`.

Comment: even if you have `cl.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin"` it doesn't mean that `pip` can find it - you would have to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin"` to `PATH`

Comment: was added that but the error still exists.....

Answer (score 1):

I've met this problem too. And I tried the methods listed in Internet and not work. Either install Microsoft Visual Studio with cl.exe in computer or add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin" to PATH. Just didn't work for me. Then as there's error shows in the middle of the error mesg:

> error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
>   .----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for
>   Twisted   Running setup.py clean for Twisted Failed to build Twisted

It mentioned Twisted, so I install Twisted first and it worked.
You can install the correct version of Twisted in below link:
[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)